# Idempiere Email Systems

Tags: java, java-web-start

I want to find the email module inside the system code. Could someone inform me where is this module by default? Or if you can inform me good places to find the documentation of this system I would be very grateful,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

most of the code related to mailing is in the class org.compiere.util.EMail, you can find that class in the project org.adempiere.base

About project documentation, you can find in the wiki: https://wiki.idempiere.org/en/Main_Page

Also, functional documentation from former project adempiere is a good source, for example: http://www.adempiere.com

Regards,

Carlos Ruiz